# Разделение дней недели

Tags: plsql, дата, sql

Имеется некий параметр, который анализируется ежедневно в обязательном порядке. Значение параметра в будние дни составляет порядка 70-100 единиц, в выходные - может упасть до нуля. Вопрос в том, как реализовать на pl/sql алгоритм, который давал нам возможность оценки среднего значения параметра без учета выходных дней (в идеале, еще и других красных дней календаря) за неделю, месяц, год, произвольное время. Можно ли реализовать это функцией `DAYOFYEAR( date)` , как я понимаю, все субботы и воскресения будут  кратны 7 и 8 для 2012 года? Или функцией `%w номер дня недели (0 - это воскресенье)` для анализа данных за неделю?

Comment: можно разбивать дату на составляющие при вставке. в таком случае не придется применять функции каждый раз

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример

Answer (score 3):

Проще смотреть на номер дня недели: DAYOFWEEK

Comment: Как мне отсеять (выбросить) из расчета эти дни? По сути, если DAYOFYEAR( date)/7=целое число, то не принимаем значение параметра за эту дату во нимание и также для DAYOFYEAR( date)/8

Comment: WHERE DAYOFWEEK(date) NOT IN (6,7)

Comment: Это только для первой недели года - это само собой разумеется. Мне интересен случай применения алгоритма на **весь** год

Comment: Функция DAYOFWEEK возвращает номер дня в неделе. Подумайте над этим

Comment: Стоп, стоп, стоп..... Туплю... Все еще думал о номере дня в году